# Tomcat NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller many Updators causes OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, tomcat, nio

This issue happened twice during the last two weeks. Every time (after more than 24 hours) the process ram was around 500mb and then it starts to rise - in 10-15 minutes it got to 4g (Xmx) and threw OutOfMemory. After that Tomcat became useless.

The process runs on jdk 1.6.30 and tomcat 7.0.42 on ubuntu 12.04 using Nio connector with default settings.
The server implements async servlet request to provide long polling (push) mechanism.

From the heap dump it appears all the heap is filled with [EPollArrayWrapper.Updator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/sun/nio/ch/EPollArrayWrapper.java#EPollArrayWrapper.Updator) instances coming from the BlockPoller-1 thread.

The code responsible for adding Updators is [updateRegistrations](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/sun/nio/ch/EPollArrayWrapper.java#EPollArrayWrapper.updateRegistrations%28%29) but my understanding stops here.

Any help on how to debug / reproduce this scenario or reference to known issues on the Tomcat/Java mailing lists is appreciated.

Comment: What on earth is OOO?

Comment: a typo for OOM. edited

Comment: It looks similar to the issue described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20475290/3080094). Apart from a heap dump, a thread dump ("kill -3") might also help investigating the issue.